# jQuery option to show input disappears

Tags: jquery, html

I have this simple `<select>` that should display an input if "Other" option is selected. However, if I open/close select, or pick any other option, "Other" disappears.

Here's what I mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $milestones = $(".other"),
        $selector = $('#source');

    $selector.change(function() {
        var selected = $selector.find('option:selected').attr('class');

        $milestones.hide();
        $('#' + selected).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

And below is HTML that holds select as well as hidden div to show the input:

```
<div class="field text">
    <label>Where did you hear about us?</label>
    <select name="source" id="source">
        <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="Other" class="other">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="field text">
    <div id="other" class="hideme">
        <label>Sources:</label><input type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to show input while `option.other` is selected. So here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var $selector = $('#source');

    $selector.change(function() {
        var showOther = $('option.other').is(':selected');
        $('#other').toggle(showOther);
    });
});
```

And for that purpose, you should hide input from start, and let [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) do its job.

```
.hideme {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kWSrh/

Answer (score 1):

You were hiding your `.other` element instead of the input box.  Look at these changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hideme').hide();
  $selector = $('#source');

  $selector.change(function() {
    var selected = $selector.find('option:selected').attr('class');

    $('.hideme').hide();
    $('#' + selected).show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sBw5X/